# Error al usar Font Awesome iconos

Tags: javascript, angular, font-awesome

Quería agregar los iconos de Font Awesome para usar dentro de mi aplicación que desarollo siguiendo [el siguiente MOOC](https://www.coursera.org/learn/angular/supplement/Cz6ZK/exercise-instructions-header-and-footer) pero generó un error que no entendí.

Primero uso NPM para buscar Font Awesome en el proyecto escribiendo lo siguiente en el indicador:

```
npm install font-awesome@4.7.0 --save
```

Luego, agreguo un nuevo archivo llamado _variables.scss en la carpeta src y agregue lo siguiente:

```
$fa-font-path : '../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts';
```

Luego, abra el archivo styles.scss y actualícelo de la siguiente manera:

```
. . .

@import 'variables';
@import '../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';

. . .
```

Pero cuando inicio el servido con `ng serve --open` obtengo lo siguiente :

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Teaching\Me\FullStack\Angular\conFusion>ng serve --open
     10% building 3/3 modules 0 activei ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:4200/webpack-dev-server/
    i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
    i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to //index.html

```
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.08 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 122 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.09 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 394 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 339 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2019-08-26T10:11:22.403Z - Hash: 8fbb15623a903204f6d1 - Time: 11587ms

ERROR in node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/mock/mock-match-media.d.ts:62:22 - error TS2420: Class 'MockMediaQueryList' incorrectly implements interface 'MediaQueryList'.
  Type 'MockMediaQueryList' is missing the following properties from type 'MediaQueryList': onchange, addEventListener, removeEventListener, dispatchEvent

62 export declare class MockMediaQueryList implements MediaQueryList {
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/mock/mock-match-media.d.ts:79:27 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaQueryListListener'.

79     addListener(listener: MediaQueryListListener): void;
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/mock/mock-match-media.d.ts:81:23 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaQueryListListener'.

81     removeListener(_: MediaQueryListListener): void;
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/server-match-media.d.ts:11:22 - error TS2420: Class 'ServerMediaQueryList' incorrectly implements interface 'MediaQueryList'.
  Type 'ServerMediaQueryList' is missing the following properties from type 'MediaQueryList': onchange, addEventListener, removeEventListener, dispatchEvent

11 export declare class ServerMediaQueryList implements MediaQueryList {
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/server-match-media.d.ts:28:27 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaQueryListListener'.

28     addListener(listener: MediaQueryListListener): void;
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/server-match-media.d.ts:30:23 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaQueryListListener'.

30     removeListener(_: MediaQueryListListener): void;
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/server-match-media.d.ts:42:15 - error TS2416: Property '_registry' in type 'ServerMatchMedia' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'MatchMedia'.
  Type 'Map<string, ServerMediaQueryList>' is not assignable to type 'Map<string, MediaQueryList>'.
    Type 'ServerMediaQueryList' is missing the following properties from type 'MediaQueryList': onchange, addEventListener, removeEventListener, dispatchEvent

42     protected _registry: Map<string, ServerMediaQueryList>;
                 ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/server-match-media.d.ts:54:15 - error TS2416: Property '_buildMQL' in type 'ServerMatchMedia' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'MatchMedia'.
  Type '(query: string) => ServerMediaQueryList' is not assignable to type '(query: string) => MediaQueryList'.
    Type 'ServerMediaQueryList' is not assignable to type 'MediaQueryList'.

54     protected _buildMQL(query: string): ServerMediaQueryList;
                 ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/observable-media/observable-media.d.ts:11:14 - error TS2416: Property 'subscribe' in type 'ObservableMedia' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Subscribable<MediaChange>'.
  Type '(next?: (value: MediaChange) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void) => Subscription' is not assignable to type '{ (observer?: PartialObserver<MediaChange>): Unsubscribable; (next: null, error: null, complete: () => void): Unsubscribable; (next: null, error: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Unsubscribable; (next: (value: MediaChange) => void, error: null, complete: () => void): Unsubscribable; (next?: (value: Medi...'.
    Types of parameters 'next' and 'observer' are incompatible.
      Type 'PartialObserver<MediaChange>' is not assignable to type '(value: MediaChange) => void'.
        Type 'NextObserver<MediaChange>' is not assignable to type '(value: MediaChange) => void'.
          Type 'NextObserver<MediaChange>' provides no match for the signature '(value: MediaChange): void'.

11     abstract subscribe(next?: (value: MediaChange) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription;
                ~~~~~~~~~

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

El codigo esta en el MOOC pero si necesitan el repositorio, digame.

## Actualizacion

Hicé un `ng update --all` y ya no tengo los errores. Sin embargo en `app.component.html` cuando anadi los components footer y header

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-menu></app-menu>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

No tengo más renderizado en el localhost. Pero si elimino el encabezado y el pie de página, vuelvo a tener el renderizado. Sin embargo, para el primer caso como para el otro no tengo ningún error.

Answer (score 0):

En principio solo con importarlo a los angular.json, en styles, debería funcionar.
Te dejo un link a continuación
https://medium.com/@smarrerof/c%C3%B3mo-arrancar-un-proyecto-angular-6-utilizando-bootstrap-4-y-font-awesome-4-5322c834c117
Y si no prueba a llamar desde el index.html al cdn de font-awesome

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Espero que te sirva.
Un saludo.